# Not able to uplaod file on googledrive?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I want to save uploaded file in Google Drive using PHP for this.I'm not getting any  response for this. If anybody can suggest would be appreciated. Below is my code
I am download API form this github I Can't get output Please help Me

```
<?php
session_start();
$url_array = explode('?', 'http://'.$_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url = $url_array[0];

require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('<client Id>');
$client->setClientSecret('<client secret>');
$client->setRedirectUri($url);
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    echo  $_SESSION['accessToken'] ;
    $_SESSION['accessToken'] = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    header('location:'.$url);exit;
} elseif (!isset($_SESSION['accessToken'])) {
    $client->authenticate();
}
$files= array();
$dir = dir('files');
while ($file = $dir->read()) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        $files[] = $file;
    }
}
$dir->close();
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
    $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $file = new Google_DriveFile();
    foreach ($files as $file_name) {
        $file_path = 'files/'.$file_name;
        $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);
        $file->setTitle($file_name);
        $file->setDescription('This is a '.$mime_type.' document');
        $file->setMimeType($mime_type);
        $service->files->insert(
            $file,
            array(
                'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
                'mimeType' => $mime_type
            )
        );
    }
    finfo_close($finfo);
    header('location:'.$url);exit;
}
include 'index.phtml';
```

Comment: On a sidenote, but I think you slipped when adding the tags and accidently submitted "javascript" as one of them.

Comment: @entiendoNull Thanks for yuour reply I didn't understand Please Explained Step by step. am I used right version of google drive APK

Comment: there are some samples here that might help you https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples

Comment: After run this code Google drive  redirect to correct page but not get response and image not uploaded on Google drive

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the multipart (see [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/media_upload)) upload method from google.

```
// Getting Files
$files= array();
$dir = dir('files');
while ($file = $dir->read()) {
  if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            $files[] = $file;
  }
}
$dir->close();

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    // set access token
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);

    // service object
    $service = new Google_DriveService($client);

    // drive file object
    $file = new Google_DriveFile();

    foreach ($files as $file_name) {

        $file_path = 'files/'.$file_name;

        $file->setTitle($file_name);

        // Use create instead of insert 
        // store response on $result array
        $result[] = $service->files->create(
             $file,
             array(
                'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
                'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
                'uploadType' => 'multipart'
             )
        );
    }

    // check response
    print_r($result);       
}
```

You have to set `'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream'` for all type of file. And if you are sending the metadata use uploadtype as multipart!.

I have not tested this code. Let me know if it works for you